# PHP correct indentation?

Tags: php, indentation

I'm a beginner PHP coder, recently I've been told I indent my code not correctly.
They say this is wrong:

```
    if($something) {
        do_something();
        }
    else {
        something_more();
        and_more();
        }
```

While this is right?

```
    if($something) {
        do_something();
    } else {
        something_more();
        and_more();
    }
```

Really? I am willing to become opensource coder in nearest future so that's why I'm asking how to write code in a good way.

Comment: Second one is way more readable, as it really shows nested code blocks. And without waste of space as in the accepted answer. Just try to scroll a couple of screens with such a waste and you'll revert to your compact mode :)

Comment: yeah you're right, I see second way is specified in multiple places as default. Though I don't really like it, maybe I should switch to it. I guess I should have rephrased my question to "which PHP indentation style you find more readable" to see what's best for public :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both ways will run just fine. Whichever is more comfortable for you and your team would be the way to go. I personally favor the second example, or something alone these lines:

```
if ($something)
{
  do_something();
}
else
{
  do_something_else();
  pet_the_ponies();
}
```

There's no real *right* answer to this.

Comment: There is this theoretical thing called a style guide that some projects may or may not use, it " If a style guide exists then follow it, but lacking direction on style, "There's no real right answer to this" as Sampson says

Comment: I programmed years with brackets `{` following the statement - until the day I saw that you can put the brackets onto the next line. When I started having a separate line for brackets, all the code was way easier to read. Also with editors like VSCode the opening and closing brackets get highlighted and you see easily where the code block starts and ends. Further I prefer to have function calls with an empty line in between. The more readable the code, the less mistakes you will do. And: Don't forget to comment your code (for you and for others)!

Answer (score 4):

In many cases, coding standards say, "match the style of the file you're editing," ie. don't change conventions if the file already has a given brace and whitespace style.

I would look over the coding standards for some popular projects to get a feel for what some patch wranglers expect:

- [MediaWiki coding conventions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Coding_conventions)
- [WordPress Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards)

&c.

Answer (score 2):

There are many Coding Standards. @Adam gave You two links, I give You another: [Zend PHP Coding Standard](http://zendframework.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/PHP+Coding+Standard+(draft)) You can choose, what You want, but You should choose most popular standard, I think.

You can use even [Code Conventions for the Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv) It doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniters user guide got some great tips on how to write your code: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html

Some are really good, but some you'll have to mix and match to get your own good style. But as said before me you should stick to one style and if you're jumping into another project you should follow the style already set. There's no right or wrong in how to style you're code, it's mostly so that you don't get lost when going back to the code after a few months.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you follow the [PEAR coding standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php). Not because they're the best, or because I like them, but because they're the most common amongst popular PHP frameworks (Symfony2, Zend Framework and others follow them for the most part, little details don't really matter).

After all, that's the whole purpose of a Coding **Standard**. To be a standard that everyone follows, no matter whether they like it or not.

Of course, if you're coding within an existing project, do not blindly follow that, try to follow whatever coding style is used in the files you are editing.