# Correcting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE

Tags: php

I am at my wits end trying to figure out why my else declaration is failing with unexpected T_ELSE. I know that is a bracket problem, but for the life of me, I cannot see it. Can someone please point out my error. Thanks

```
<?php


// Connection config
function runSQL($rsql) {
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname   = "sample";
    $connect = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die ("Error: could not connect to database");
    $db = mysql_select_db($dbname);
    $result = mysql_query($rsql) or die (mysql_error());
    return $result;
    mysql_close($connect);
    }
?>
<?php
    // test vars from jquery form
    $status = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['status']);
    $company = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['company']);
    $requested = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['requested']);
    $activity = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['activity']);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['address2']);
    $service = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['service']);
    $box = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['box_rtv']);
    $authorised = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['kt_name_usr']);
    $dept = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['rtv_dept']);

    // Split the box if multiples
    $array = split('[,]', $_REQUEST['box_rtv']);

    // Loop to split if multiple request and check DB for dupe entries
    foreach ($array as $box) {
        $sql = "SELECT item FROM act WHERE item = '$box'";echo $sql;
        $result = runSQL($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        // If there are dupe entries, send message to jquery
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
            echo 'Error';
            return;
        }
    } else {

        // If no dupes, then enter values into DB.
        $form = array();
        foreach ($array as $box) {
            $form = array('dept'=>$dept,
            'company'=>$company,
            'address'=>$address,
            'service'=>$service,
            'box'=>$box,
            'destroydate'=>$destroydate,
            'authorised'=>$authorised,
            'submit'=>$submit);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `temp` (service, activity, department, company, address, user, date, item, new) VALUES ('$service', '$activity', '$dept', '$company', '$address', '$requested', NOW(), '$box', 1)";
            $result = runSQL($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Typical indentation problem. Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675368/php-correct-indentation could help...

Comment: typical zero effort, "let's post the whole code" question.

Comment: @John FYI Another user on SO suggested formatting code this way.

Comment: @Karoly How on earth is it zero effort. I posted the code so experts could see it in it's entireity not asking anyone to code anything, just another pair of eyes. push ya ego in.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't about giving a ready-to-use solution. *Experts*, as you say, love to see what you tried, and how it failed, that's called *learning*. Here you just throw some code, asking us "there a problem, just solve it". Besides, an IDE could have solved this one much faster than anyone.

Comment: @user1532468: 1) zero effort in the sense that we need **minimal code which reproduces the problem**. 2) whenever I see someone mention the ego... LOL.

Comment: Jeez, wind your neck in. I haven't asked for a ready made solution, just another pair of eyes to spot something I have missed or cannot see. How is that coding?

Comment: "Another user on SO suggested formatting code this way." - I highly doubt it (= either you haven't understood it, or worse...). feel free to link a proof. and please stop abusing citizens here.

Comment: @Karoly He actually recoded it. Thanks for your input :-(

Comment: @Karoly I actually owe you an apology. It was on another experts forum not SO.

Comment: thank you, appriciated :) for further reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `else` is currently applying to your `foreach`, which is obviously not what you intended! Pay attention to the `}` positions.

Answer (score 3):

You just need one `}` to close your `if` clause

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
        echo 'Error';
        return;
    } // <-- Remove this
} else {
```

Comment: Felix now I get unexpected $end after removing }. How do I correct. Thanks

Comment: Please check again. I cannot see any `$end` in your code?

Comment: xdebug-error xe-parse-error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end line 62. That is the end of the page.