# Multiple if else in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have re-written this question because of all the down votes and it would seem that either no one understood the question or was unwilling to help a newbie. So I'll as it this way: Can someone tell/show me why this code does not work? (500 error)

OR... at the very least point me in the right direction? I AM WILLING TO LEARN, I just don't know where to begin or who/where to learn from as I am not sure what to even ask other than how do you run multiple "else" statements... that however left me more confused than I already am though!

Any "HELP" would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "****";
$password   = "***";
$dbname     = "***";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$bname    = $_POST['bname'];
$baddress = $_POST['baddress'];
$bcity    = $_POST['bcity'];
$bstate   = $_POST['bstate'];
$zipcode  = $_POST['zipcode'];

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
  {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

$sql    = "SELECT Login FROM `USERS` WHERE Business_Name = '" . $_POST["bname"] . "' AND Business_Address = '" . $_POST["baddress"] . "' AND Business_State = '" . $_POST["bstate"] . "' AND Business_Zip = '" . $_POST["zipcode"] . "' LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
      {
        echo "https://www.***.com/realsite.php?Login=" . $row["Login"] . "";
      }
  }
else
  {
    $sql    = "SELECT Login FROM `DATA` WHERE Business_Name = '" . $_POST["bname"] . "' AND Business_Address = '" . $_POST["baddress"] . "' AND Business_State = '" . $_POST["bstate"] . "' AND Business_Zip = '" . $_POST["zipcode"] . "' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
      {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
          {
            echo "https://www.***.com/demo.php?Login=" . $row["Login"] . "";
          }
      }
    else
      {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `DATA` (Business_Name, Business_Address, Business_City, Business_State, Business_Zip)
                SELECT '$bname', '$baddress', '$bcity', '$bstate', '$zipcode' FROM (SELECT 1) t
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Login, Business_Name,Business_Address FROM `DATA` WHERE Business_Name='$bname' AND Business_Address='$baddress')";


        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
          {

            echo "<a href='https://www.servedwell.com/realsite.php?Login=" . $row["Login"] . "'>LINK</a>";

          }        
        else
          {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
          }
      }
    mysqli_close($conn);

  }
?>
```

Comment: First of all, please post this code with some sort of proper indentation, so that it is more easily visible what belongs to what.

Comment: So what exactly is stopping you from making your third query in the else branch of the second part then?

Comment: 04FS: I'll read up on "proper indentation". I have no idea what that even means in relation to scripts but I'm sure it's important.   As for what is stopping me.... I've tried putting it in the "{
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }" area and bumping down the error, but it breaks the script entirely. You did read the opening statement about me being one of those "nubes" right? I would not be here if I already new the answer ;-)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Dharman: Thank you. Finally got some info I can actually use and learn from! As to my question that now has four(4) down votes, haha....(WOW, just wow... ) Any idea how to accomplish what I am asking?

Comment: I have re-written this question because of all the down votes as it would seem that either no one understood the question or was unwilling to help a newbie.

Comment: @Thor Indentation means format your source code, so other people and yourself can cleary see what belongs where. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675368/php-correct-indentation for further inspiration.

Comment: @Thor In addition to that, you are probably getting an HTTP-500 response because of the poor indentation and the resulting oversight. The last "else" statement with the Error is not supposed to be there. The "}" needs to be above the else to close out the IF before the else. If my edit with the indentation fixes goes through, this should include the change and make it a valid php script. Try it and report back if it still produces unwanted results with an updated Question.

Comment: @Ancaron Thank you for the link (proper indentation) and you are right! If it was properly indented I would have noticed my error. (at least I "think" I would have, haha) Your edit did in fact fix the issue! Now I am not sure how to mark your answer/edit as the fix, giving you proper credit.

Comment: I am not sure, that simply formatting your code and fixing 1 syntax error is ground for an answer. I am just glad your code works :)

Comment: Well, thank you anyway. Because of that little syntax correction (and telling me about formatting properly), I have built out three more scripts and they are all working like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @Ancaron for properly formatting code and correcting a syntax error. Final posted code works fine.